# Background Audio Agent and Media Player in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I stuck in a big problem I am playing audio in background using BackgroundAudioPlayer working fine while I am playing another audio file using MediaElement on foreground the background sound is stopped.I want to play both sound simultaneously background and foreground please let me how it will be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaElement` and `BackgroundAudioPlayer` are exclusive - you can only use one of these at a time.

You are able to play additional sounds using the XNA SoundEffect APIs however. For example of these APIs see [this blog entry](http://davidvoyles.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/playing-sound-effects-through-windows-phone-8/).

Comment: Thank for considering me but I think you are not getting me my problem is that I am playing a sound in background and want to play play more sound except the background while moving in another page.I mean i have to play a different audio file in each page and background audio will be playing continuously.

Comment: You must use SoundEffect to play the page foreground audio then.

Comment: Thans I will try for background audio What will be used?